# How to prevent automatic justification of references?

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I have a reference entry in the bibliography that appears as follows:

```
[50] AB MySQL.    MySQL:  The  world's  most  popular  open  source  database,
     http://www.mysql.com/, 2005.
```

How to prevent auto-justification for specific references?

Comment: You could specify your URLs using the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url). It does a very good job in breaking URLs at the text block edge. I'm not sure whether this what you're after. Or are you looking for a "ragged right" alignment?

Comment: Thanks for the url package info, however, as you guessed, I am looking for left-aligning the text in this case.

Comment: You could just add `\raggedright` (left-aligned with no hyphenation on the right) before `\bibliography{...}` (or `\printbibliography` if you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

Comment: With `biblatex`, you could use `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright}`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Nobody knows what you're doing, let alone answer your question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To typeset the whole bibliography `\raggedright`, do one of the following:

1) If you're using a manually created `thebibliography` environment, add `\raggedright` at the beginning of the environment:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\raggedright

\bibitem{test} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}
```

2) If you create your bibliography with BibTeX, but without the help of the `natbib` or the `biblatex` package, enclose `\bibliography{<mybib>}` within a group and add `\raggedright` inside the group:

```
\begingroup
\raggedright

\bibliography{<mybib>}
\endgroup
```

3) If you're using either `natbib` or `biblatex`, simply redefine `\bibfont`:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright}
```

If you really, really want to typeset only specific references `\raggedright` (which is rather inconsistent), you could trick `biblatex` into doing so by (ab)using the `execute` and `addendum` fields of the respective entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha -- \lipsum*[1]},
}
@misc{B02,
  execute ={\raggedright},
  addendum = {\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\nopunct},
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo -- \lipsum*[1]},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie -- \lipsum*[1]},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]