# How do I reduce whitespace or stretching in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, white-space

How do I reduce whitespace in between words in the bibliography? It seems it's trying to stretch things out to fit into the column. For example:

[image: example]

Here is the test document:

```
% test.tex
\title{Article Title}
\author{Some Author}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{LinkReference1,
  author = {Xxxxxxxxxx, Xxxxx},
  title = {Xxxxx-xxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: Xxxxxx Xxxx},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section1Title}
Hello World.
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}

% Create PDF on Linux:
% FILE=test; pkill -9 -f ${FILE} &>/dev/null; rm -f ${FILE}*aux ${FILE}*bbl ${FILE}*bib ${FILE}*blg ${FILE}*log ${FILE}*out ${FILE}*pdf &>/dev/null; pdflatex -halt-on-error ${FILE}; bibtex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && (xdg-open ${FILE}.pdf &)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many `.bst` styles use the command `\newblock` to separate (larger) chunks of information. In the example the `.bbl` file will contain a `\newblock` after the author name directly at the position marked in red.

```
\bibitem{LinkReference1}
Xxxxx Xxxxxxxxxx.
\newblock Xxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: Xxxxxx xxxx.
```

Note that there is a normal space (or in this case line break) before `\newblock` as well.

The standard classes define

```
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
```

which means that an additional (quite) stretchable space is inserted by `\newblock`.

`natbib`, which you use, also has

```
\renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}
```

but does that definition inside `thebibliography`, which means that if you want to modify `\newblock` you will have to either redefine `thebibliography` or work from within the environment (for example by manually modifying the `.bbl` file or by using `@preamble` together with a `.bst` file that executes the `@preamble` commands within the environment [there are some that do this, but the majority of styles executes `@preamble` before `\begin{thebibliography}`]).

In your example then

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection
 \parindent\z@
 \bibpreamble
 \bibfont
 \list{\@biblabel{\the\c@NAT@ctr}}{\@bibsetup{#1}\global\c@NAT@ctr\z@}%
 \ifNAT@openbib
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}%
 \else
   \renewcommand\newblock{}%
 \fi
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.\@m
 \let\NAT@bibitem@first@sw\@firstoftwo
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite
}{%
 \bibitem@fin
 \bibpostamble
 \def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}{Empty `thebibliography' environment}%
 }%
 \endlist
 \bibcleanup
}%
\makeatother
```

would remove the additional space inserted by `\newblock`. But the spacing does not get better

[image: Example bibliography: There are huge spaces between all words in the first line.]

Arguably it gets worse, because the given and family name, which form one unit, are separated by the same space that separates the name and the title.

---

Line breaking in the bibliography is hard at the best of times (names and technical jargon might be hard to hyphenate properly, URLs make things complicated, ...), but two-column mode it gets even harder because the available space is much smaller than usual. It is therefore expected that space needs to be stretched and compressed a bit for full justification.

In this case it is well worth considering setting the bibliography ragged right, i.e. turning off the justification. See for example [How to prevent automatic justification of references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41134/35864). LaTeX will stop stretching space, but the text will not line up at the end of the line. Since the bibliography is list-like and probably has a high number of lines that don't meet the right margin anyway, the visual effect will not be as big as in a normal paragraph of flowing text.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{LinkReference1,
  author = {Xxxxxxxxxx, Xxxxx},
  title = {Xxxxx-xxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: Xxxxxx Xxxx},
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

the overall result is much more pleasant

[image: No excessive white space in the first line. The <code>\newblock</code> still adds a wee bit of additional space after the period.]

If you like hyphenation in ragged right text, you may want to look into [`ragged2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)'s `\RaggedRight`.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer, thank you! Not only does it solve my issue with `\raggedright` but it really helps me understand the theory behind everything.

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out by moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468704/156280), when using `natbib`, one has to redefine `\newblock` inside the `thebibliography` environment. A relatively simple solution that does exactly this is:

```
\let \thebibliographyorig \thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
    \thebibliographyorig{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\newblock}{}%
}
```